# SQLITE_ERROR - SQL error or missing database (near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error)

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, auto-increment

I'm trying to create a table in my newly created SQLite database. For some reason I'm getting an SQLException:

```
try {
        logger.debug("Trying to create table powerperms_permissions if not exists");
        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS powerperms_permissions ( "
                + "id INT NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "uuid VARCHAR ( 64 ) NOT NULL,"
                + "permission VARCHAR ( 64 ) NOT NULL,"
                + "world VARCHAR ( 32 ) NULL,"
                + "PRIMARY KEY ( id ) );");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Couldn't create permissions table",e);
    }
```

throws

```
[07:49:17 ERROR]: [PowerPerms] Couldn't create permissions table
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383) ~[spigot-1.10.jar:git-Spigot-6016ac7-10c10b3]
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387) ~[spigot-1.10.jar:git-Spigot-6016ac7-10c10b3]
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374) ~[spigot-1.10.jar:git-Spigot-6016ac7-10c10b3]
    at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method) ~[spigot-1.10.jar:git-Spigot-6016ac7-10c10b3]
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123) ~[spigot-1.10.jar:git-Spigot-6016ac7-10c10b3]
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.execute(Stmt.java:113) ~[spigot-1.10.jar:git-Spigot-6016ac7-10c10b3]
    at eu.taigacraft.powerperms.Main.registerSqlite(Main.java:240) [PowerPerms_v1.0.jar:?]
    at eu.taigacraft.powerperms.Main$2.run(Main.java:48) [PowerPerms_v1.0.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:71) [spigot-1.10.jar:git-Spigot-6016ac7-10c10b3]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_10_R1.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:53) [spigot-1.10.jar:git-Spigot-6016ac7-10c10b3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_72]
```

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`AUTOINCREMENT` keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) only with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, not `INT NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the primary key comes before the auto_increment then it will work

Answer (score -2):

There must be a database,  auto increment is spelled like AUTO_INCREMENT and not null may affect your code depending on your dbms

Comment: this answer does not apply to SQLITE, it would e.g. apply to MySQL